# Is it good programming to use look-up tables (two dimensional array) instead of maths operators?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

By using a two dimensional array, I have removed the need for maths operators and speeded up a programme to calculate 2 ^ n by 50%.  This can be achieved because the maximum remainder when multiplying by two is 1 i.e. 2 * 9.
Do experienced C programmers consider this a sound approach as I am still learning C programming?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

clock_t start, end;
double cpu_time_used;

int main(void) {
    int exp;
    printf("Enter power: ");
    scanf("%d", &exp);

    int *pwr;

    printf("%d \n", exp);

    pwr = (int *)calloc(exp, sizeof(int));

    // Check if the memory has been allocated
    if (pwr == NULL) {
        printf("pwr memory not allocated.\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        // memory has been successfully allocated
        printf("memory allocated (calloc)\n");
    }

    int lkt[10][10] = {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
        {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7},
        {8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5},
        {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7}, {8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9},
    };
    int a, b, c, d;

    *(pwr + exp - 1) = 2;

    for (int j = 0; j < exp - 1; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < exp; ++i) {
            a = *(pwr + i);
            b = *(pwr + i + 1);
            *(pwr + i) = *(*(lkt + a) + b);
        }
    }

    int z = 0;
    while (pwr[z] == 0) {
        ++z;
    }

    for (int i = z; i < exp; ++i) {
        printf("%d", *(pwr + i));
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(pwr);

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\nTime taken to run programme = %f ", cpu_time_used);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is good programming to use proper indentation :)

Comment: This is sound approach when the performance is critical and these operations are your bottleneck.

Comment: But somehow I doubt that it has any improvement over the proper implementation of `2^n`, which is a simple bit-shifting operation. Lookup tables are usually used for calculations that have no intrinsic equivalents in the computer instruction set (or somewhat simple combinations of these) , such as trigonometric functions or some other complex calculations.

Comment: Looking things up in a table requires address arithmetic and fetching from memory (at least nominally; details are system specific). Code interacts with other code and should not be measured in isolation without considering this—a lookup may be fast by itself but may push something out of cache that slows down other code.

Comment: `start` is not set in your posted code, aside from its implicit initialization to zero.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem per se using look up tables to optimize performance, using more data to save some execution time, but it does have some drawbacks: it tends to make the code less readable and more difficult to understand and debug.

Note as a matter of fact these issues in your code:

- using the array syntax `pwr[i]` is more readable than `*(pwr + i)` and obviously even more for `*(*(lkt + a) + b)` written as `lkt[a][b]`.  Note that the compiler will not care and generate similar if not identical code.
- reading `b` with `b = *(pwr + i + 1);` when `i = exp - 1` in the last iteration of the inner loop will have undefined behavior because you read beyond the end of the allocated array.
- if your goal is performance, finding a better algorithm is where you should focus your efforts. The main issue in this computation is the conversion to base 10.  You could compute 9 digits at a time in 32-bit ints.
- you could also reduce the size of the allocated array and the number of iterations in the inner loop using `int digits = 1 + exp / 3;` which is always larger than the number of decimal digits of 2<sup>exp</sup>.  This will make the code run 3 times faster.
- you should also avoid timing input and output operations, and since `start` is never set you are also timing the startup code.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;
    int exp;

    printf("Enter power: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &exp) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("%d\n", exp);

    int digits = 1 + exp / 3;
    int *pwr = calloc(digits + 1, sizeof(*pwr));

    // Check if the memory has been allocated
    if (pwr == NULL) {
        printf("pwr memory not allocated.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    static int const lkt[10][10] = {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 },
        { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 },
        { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7 },
        { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 },
        { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 },
        { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7 },
        { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
    };

    start = clock();

    pwr[digits - 1] = 2;

    for (int j = 0; j < exp - 1; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < digits; ++i) {
            int a = pwr[i];
            int b = pwr[i + 1];
            pwr[i] = lkt[a][b];
        }
    }

    int z = 0;
    while (pwr[z] == 0) {
        ++z;
    }

    end = clock();

    for (int i = z; i < digits; ++i) {
        putc('0' + pwr[i]);
    }
    putc("\n");
    free(pwr);

    cpu_time_used = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\nTime taken to run programme = %f\n", cpu_time_used);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chqrlie. I have put in if(i + 1 == nlen) {b = 0;} which should avoid unpredictable behaviour. Unfortunately it slows the calcultion down by 14%

Comment: @IanStewart: Allocating one extra entry for the array fixes this problem without the need for an extra test.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is a *good* solution depends entirely on context.

Using look-up tables to grab a precomputed solution to an expensive calculation out of the data-section of your executable is a good solution if you're prioritizing speed over memory, but a bad one if you're prioritizing memory over speed.

For instance if I was running this program on a tiny little microcontroller with limited flash memory space, and I needed it to be able to do other complex tasks, I might decide it's worth spending a few hundred clock cycles to compute the value instead of storing a giant look-up table in my flash.

On the other hand if I was running this program on my gaming computer and could not care less about 400 extra bytes in my program to save a few milliseconds, then I'd probably use a look-up table.

It's also worth noting that it may be comparatively easier to make (and not catch) a mistake when writing out a look-up table in code, than it would be to find a logical error in an algorithm that you write, so in some cases you may make your source code harder to read and debug if you use the look-up table.

Comment: In such cases I generate the look-up table by using the proven code that it is intended to replace, outputting the proper source code syntax, so it's just a copy/paste job to put it in the next version of the main code.

Comment: I use excel for this :D Or, if startup time isn't critical, the lookup table can be precomputed when the program starts.